# How to override DefaultListableBeanFactory in Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Are there ways to override properties of `DefaultListableBeanFactory` in Spring Boot application?
For example, I want to set the `DefaultListableBeanFactory.allowBeanDefinitionOverriding` property to `false`.

**EDIT**

*Use case.*

I have pretty plain class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class MyTempComponent {
    private String value;
}
```

Which I want use as @Bean in my application but this bean can be defined several times, for example:

```
@Configuration
class TestConfiguration1 {
    @Bean
    MyTempComponent myTempComponent() {
        return new MyTempComponent("Value 1");
    }
}
@Configuration
class TestConfiguration2 {
    @Bean
    MyTempComponent myTempComponent() {
        return new MyTempComponent("Value 2");
    }
}
```

Also there is a consumer of that bean:

```
@Component
class TestConfiguration3 {

    private MyTempComponent myTempComponent;

    @Autowired
    public TestConfiguration3(MyTempComponent myTempComponent) {
        this.myTempComponent = myTempComponent;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.myTempComponent.getValue());
    }
}
```

When an application starts it prints "Value 2" message, i.e. initializes myTempComponent bean from TestConfiguration2.
I want to prohibit creation of that bean (and any other beans) if there are two or more candidates.

As I realized I can reach this goal via setting `DefaultListableBeanFactory.allowBeanDefinitionOverriding` to `false`.
But how to set this property in Spring Boot application? Could you provide an example please?

Comment: DefaultListableBeanFactory .setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false) should work. Did you try to look method in DefaultListableBeanFactory.java  or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe it should work but how to define it in Spring Boot app? :)

Comment: can you tell me what you want to achieve? I want to understand use-case

Comment: @ShaunakPatel I have added use case in EDIT section of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set

```
 private static class CustomAppCtxInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        applicationContext
                .getDefaultListableBeanFactory()
                .setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
    }
}
```

and then have

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        final SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.addInitializers(new CustomAppCtxInitializer());
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!